# Would a Rubik's cube be a trapdoor function?

Tags: trapdoor

It's easy to scramble a Rubik's cube but it is hard to solve, unless you know the algorithms for solving it. This makes it a trapdoor function, correct?

Comment: No, it does not. Scrambling a Rubik is the same as symmetrical encryption.

Comment: But I know an algorithm to solve it without knowing the "encryption key" of the scramble.

Comment: The algorithm to solve the Rubik can be considered bruteforcing it, while doing the shuffle backwards would be the proper decryption.

Comment: Really? I thought you would do

Comment: The algorithm to solve a cube is *not* brute forcing it — trying every possible permutation is. The algorithm to solve a cube is equivalent to a catastrophic known-plaintext cryptanalytic attack against the "Rubiks cipher".

Answer (score 10):

It might be a viable example for explaining the concept of a trapdoor function to a layman without a computer science or math background. But from a CS standpoint this is only half-true.

For a low number of `n` where `n` is the number of rotate-operations performed on the cube, it is true that finding a solution for the cube is more computationally expensive than applying the rotations. But with very high values of `n` this might change. [It was proven that any rubic's cube configuration can be solved with 20 moves or less](http://www.cube20.org/), and finding that 20 move sequence might in fact be faster than applying the "correct" sequence.

Answer (score 4):

A rubik's cube is an NP problem. It is difficult to **find a solution** to the problem but it is very easy to **verify correctness of the solution**, by just rotating the cube and checking that all sides have matching colours.

Yes, there is a widely known solution for the 3 * 3 * 3 rubik's cube. You can solve it in 20 moves because you have memorised the solution. However, there is no general solution for an n * n * n rubik's cube and finding one is terribly difficult.